# SQL not saving data despite application is able to run

Tags: mysql

I am getting this error whenever I run the app, does any one knows what is the reason behind it?

> W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive
>   InputConnection W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on
>   inactive InputConnection D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security
>   Config specified, using platform default W/IInputConnectionWrapper:
>   finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
>   W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive
>   InputConnection

Comment: just want to say, check connection string.

Comment: where do i check my connection string sir? Sorry but I am new to this!

Comment: What are you doing eventually? sorry i dont understand. Are you just scripting to your Database? Making some code and connect to DB? i dont know. What app you mean anyway?

Comment: I am trying to learn how to make a register request via android studio through the given link below. I am currently stuck at the part where data is not stored in DB. There's no problem in my PHP files either.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T7Z4GVFaT4A